# how to convert all values in a specific column to list string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am using `Pandas` to Data Analysis and I get a question as followed:

```
        city         x
190     California   37253956
2566    Texas        25145561
1860    New York     19378102
```

And I want to extract all values in `city` and convert it to list string as followed:

```
['California', 'Texas', 'New York']
```

BUT I don't know how use `map`, `applymap` or `apply` to make it right.

And I searched some relevant questions before, but I stll just couldn't figure it out.

It will be really appreciated, if anyone would help me.

Comment: Use `df['city'].tolist()`

Comment: use `df['city'].tolist()`

Comment: `df['city'].tolist()` or `df['city'].unique().tolist()` to remove duplicated entries